# Hadoop in eclipse java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, exception, hadoop, eclipselink

I'm new to hadoop and just set up my hadoop environment from online tutorial. However, when I tried to create a hadoop class in eclipse following the guide in:
http://importantfish.com/how-to-run-hadoop-in-standalone-mode-using-eclipse-on-mac-os-x/

I can run hadoop example jars and all works fine. But when I did all the steps involved within that blog and hit run in eclipse, I got NoClassDefFoundErr as:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/yarn/util/Apps
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager.setup(LocalDistributedCacheManager.java:93)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.<init>(LocalJobRunner.java:163)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner.submitJob(LocalJobRunner.java:731)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:432)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1285)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1282)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1548)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1282)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1303)
    at WordCount.main(WordCount.java:82)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.Apps
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 24 more
```

Also, I checked other posts about the similar problem. Some mentioned that you should have both common-logging-1.1.3.jar and common-logging-api-1.0.4.jar. I don't have the common-logging-api one, just can't find it and I tried to look into every folder provided by hadoop as I can.

Would you please tell me how to solve the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: you are running hadoop version-2. From what I observed, Eclispse does not support running Yarn which is Hadoop 2. The post you highlighted above uses hadoop1

Comment: so should I delete this hadoop version and change to the old one?

Comment: you dont have to. Just install hadoop version 1 in a different directory and set build path in Eclipse to point to jars in hadoop version 1 directory (follow the post above)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to include the hadoop-yarn-common-x.x.x.jar. Look for it in hadoop's lib directory.

The problem is that you are using a higher version of hadoop (2.x), this one uses yarn.

**Hint**: jar files for yarn are actually located in:

```
${HADOOP_HOME}/share/hadoop/yarn/*.jar
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also solve this issue by adding these lines in the pom file:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
        <version>x.x.x</version>
    </dependency>
```

The HDFS version numbers are listed in [this site](https://docs.oracle.com/goldengate/bd1221/gg-bd/GADBD/GUID-1A409BCB-A8A2-41CD-B9D6-4D65D356D1A5.htm)